# Why does the dispatch not work in curried function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, currying

I have a function createBoard.

```
import {Dispatch} from "redux";

export const createBoard = (boardTitle: string) => {
  console.log("boardTitle", boardTitle);
  return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    console.log("dispatch");
    try {    
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_BOARD', payload: boardTitle});
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_BOARDS_ERROR', payload: 'ADD_BOARDS_ERROR' });
      console.log("e", e);
    }
  }
}
```

In the console, I can only see the "boardTitle". Why does the following function (dispatch: Dispatch) not work? Do I have a syntax error?

Comment: How are you calling createBoard method?

Comment: You're returning a function but not invoking it?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm invoking it - dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_BOARD', payload: boardTitle});

Comment: Do you have https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk middleware to handle this thunk?

Comment: Yes, the file has an import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk' - but it is inactive (not used)